# ccDrawLine opacity?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am very new to all those OpenGL calls, but fortunately cocos2d will easily let me draw lines on the screen, like this:

```
-(void)draw {
    glColor4f(255, 255, 255,255);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(150,110), ccp(280,230));
}
```

And I get a white line.

But now, I want to make it a bit transparent, so I change the alpha value to 100. However, the line is still bright and white. Then I assumed that the values could actually range from 0.0 to 1.0. I set it to 0.2 but still no change.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need to enable blending first:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255,100);
ccDrawLine(ccp(0,110), ccp(280,230));
```

Also note that "glColor4ub" takes in unsigned bytes (0-255 for each parameter) while
"glColor4f" takes in 4 floats (0-1.0 for each parameter). Use whichever you are comfortable with.

Good luck!

Comment: You also can use `ccDrawColor4B(255,255,255,100)` instead of `glColor4ub()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Cocos2d, but the OpenGL itself requires the alpha-blending to be turned on. It's `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` which is *disabled* by default. Also, you should check the [glBlendFunc()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) function to set up the proper blending function. The usual params for the alpha-blending are `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`