# How to use openGL line drawing in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, line, draw

I like to draw a line, but cocos2d inside ccDrawLine serrate, how to draw a blurring of the line, who can help me?

```
ccDrawLine( ccp(StartP.x, StartP.y), ccp(EndP.x, EndP.y) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use ccDrawLine but I created a line with a Sprite and I animated it (see code below). In this way I was able to use custom line images made (but nevermind. that's how I did).

If you want to stick to primitives I guess you should **set the opacity of the line primitive** (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262245/ccdrawline-opacity) post which explains how) and then you could create a sequence of action that set the opacity level (e.g. start with opacity at 100%, then 75%, then back to 100% like I did with my images but using the method in the link above) to get the blurring effect..

**Code using images:**

```
CCSprite * string = [self getChildByTag:tag];
[string setOpacity:100]; 
NSMutableArray* frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
NSString*lineFrame = [NSString stringWithString:@"line0.png"];            

CCSpriteFrame* frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:lineFrame];
[frames addObject:frame];

lineFrame = [NSString stringWithString:@"line1.png"];
frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:lineFrame];
[frames addObject:frame];

lineFrame = [NSString stringWithString:@"line0.png"];
frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:lineFrame];
[frames addObject:frame];


CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:0.1f];
CCAnimate* animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
//CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];
[string runAction:animate];

[string setOpacity:75];
```

Hope that this helps..

Comment: Thank you very much, this method is used on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface CClineSprite : CCLayer
{
    CCRenderTexture * renderTarget;
    NSMutableArray  * pathArray;
    CCSprite        * pathBrush;
    CGPoint           prePosition;
}

-(void)setLinePosition:(CGPoint)position;

-(void)setLineOpacity:(GLubyte) anOpacity;

-(void)setLineScale:(float) scale;

-(void)setLineColor:(ccColor3B) color;

@end








#import "CClineSprite.h"

@implementation CClineSprite

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        renderTarget = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:s.width height:s.height];
        [renderTarget setPosition:ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2)];
        [self addChild:renderTarget z:1];
        pathBrush = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dots.png"];
        pathBrush.color = ccWHITE;
        [pathBrush setOpacity:100];
        [pathBrush setScale:0.5];
        pathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setLineOpacity:(GLubyte) anOpacity
{
    [pathBrush setOpacity:anOpacity];
}

-(void)setLineScale:(float) scale
{
    [pathBrush setScale:scale];
}

-(void)setLineColor:(ccColor3B) color
{
    [pathBrush setColor:color];
}

-(void)setLinePosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    [pathArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position]];
    [self renderPath];
}

- (void) renderPath
{
    [renderTarget clear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];
    [renderTarget begin];

    for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.count-1;i++)
    {
        CGPoint pt1;
        CGPoint pt2;

        [[pathArray objectAtIndex:i] getValue: &pt1];
        [[pathArray objectAtIndex:i + 1] getValue: &pt2];

        float distance = ccpDistance(pt1, pt2);

        if (distance > 1)
        {
            int d = (int)distance;
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i += 10)
            {
                float difx = pt2.x - pt1.x;
                float dify = pt2.y - pt1.y;
                float delta = (float)i / distance;

                [pathBrush setPosition:ccp(pt1.x + (difx * delta), pt1.y + (dify * delta))];
                [pathBrush visit];
            }
        }
    }
    [renderTarget end];
}

@end
```

USAGE:

```
CClineSprite* streak = [CClineSprite node];
[self addChild:streak z:999];
[streak setLinePosition:associatedTurtleObject.position];
[streak setLineScale:0.4];
```

To dynamically update or extend the line just use

```
[streak setLinePosition:ccp(x,y)];
```

Hope this will give you more flexibility for use

Comment: USAGE:

    CClineSprite* streak = [CClineSprite node];
    [self addChild:streak z:999];
    [streak setLinePosition:associatedTurtleObject.position];
    [streak setLineScale:0.4];



To dynamically update or extend the line just use

    [streak setLinePosition:ccp(x,y)];









Hope this will give you more flexibility for use